# How can I display are larger scale object from the gallery?

Tags: project-spark

Currently I have [this](http://kodeshare.com/sbbgJQ) Kode:

[image: Kode Line]

This will display a small circle in the middle of the screen like this:
[image: small ring]

I am trying to increase the size of this circle so it displays over the majority of the screen, more like this black circle:
[image: Bigger ring]

However, when attempting to add Scale to the Kode, it just displays "1.2" in the middle of the circle.

How can I scale up an object being displayed when that object is picked using the gallery picker?

Comment: I'm not sure since I haven't messed with Project Spark in a *long* time, but I think you could scale the actual object and then save an instance of the new one to use in Kode.

Comment: Bah, missed the edit timeout. Where are you placing the scale node?

Comment: @Rapitor I've tried several places, but usually I kept it in the block directly behind the object, like [this](http://kodeshare.com/jzMTo3).